# BRPOP non blocking in eredis

Tags: c, redis

I'm trying to use REDIS (with the eredis library) to sincronize a set of producers/workers.

A worker will post its id (say 123) into a list and will wait on a list named `wrk:123` with `BRPOP`. I wrote the code below but while the LPUSH succeed, the BRPOP returns with a null reply!

`BRPOP` works perfectly in `redis-cli`, of course.

I'm clearly doing something wrong here, but I can't tell what is it!!

```
      // Push my id to other clients
      reader = eredis_r( redis );
      sprintf(cmdbuf,"LPUSH readylist %d",myid);
      reply  = eredis_r_cmd(reader,cmdbuf);
      if (reply && reply->type == REDIS_REPLY_INTEGER) {
        printf("Reply: %lld\d",reply->integer);
      }

      // WAIT some other client to sendme data
      sprintf(cmdbuf,"BRPOP wrk:%d 0",myid);
      reply  = eredis_r_cmd(reader,cmdbuf);
      if (reply) {
        switch (reply->type) {
          case REDIS_REPLY_ERROR: printf("Reply: ERROR %.*s\n",(int)reply->len,reply->str);
                                  break;

                         default: printf("Reply type: %d\n",reply->type);
        }
      } 
      else printf("Reply is null\n");

      eredis_r_clear( reader );
      eredis_r_release( reader );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is related to the following hiredis issue:
https://github.com/redis/hiredis/issues/722
which is caused by a change in the BRPOP behaviour: when the redis connection timeout is set to a non 0 value, that timeout is also inherithed by BRPOP (and similar commands).

Setting the redis connection timeout to 0:

```
eredis_timeout(redis, 0);
```

makes the code behave as expected.